# Adding an array of 3D points to a 2D array of 3D points using numpy

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

So I have a system of 300 objects moving in a 3D space, and I'd like to record their locations at each step in time, where there are 1000 time intervals. I am getting all of their locations at once for each time interval, and then need to add them to my 2D array of points that is recording their location at each point in time.

So I initialize a 2D array of 3D points which as a shape of (300, 1000, 3) -- 300 rows, 1000 columns, where each element is a point that consists of 3 values. Now what I need to be able to do is add a new point to each row every time I get each object's new point at a time interval. So I have an array of shape (300, 3).

**Is there a way of using numpy methods (for speed) to set all of the points at that specific interval for each object at once?**

Here's how I'm doing it so far:

```
    points1000 = np.ndarray(shape=(300, 1000, 3))
    for interval in range(1000):
        obj_locations_at_interval = getallobjectlocations(interval)
        for j,_ in enumerate(obj_locations_at_interval):
        points1000[j][interval]=obj_locations_at_interval[interval]
```

Comment: Try `points1000[:, interval, :] = getallobjectlocations(interval)`.

Comment: That seems to have worked! thanks so much!